# python 3 print statement clarification

Tags: python, python-3.x

In python 2, the python print statement was not a function whereas in python 3 this has been turned to into an function

when I type `print(` I get some hovertext *(or something similar)* to

```
print(value,...,sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)
```

I know what value means but a clarification on what what those other variables mean and what are the advantages of python 3's print statement over python 2's would be appreciated `(especially sep=' ')`

Comment: `sep` is just the separator between arguments. E.g. `print("John", "Doe", sep="\t")` prints `John Doe`.

Comment: the hover statement is the specification of the print statement.

Comment: you can usually always get more info with `help(print)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you provide multiple arguments to `print` they usually get separated by a space:

```
>>> print(1, 2, 3)
1 2 3
```

`sep` lets you change that to something else:

```
>>> print(1, 2, 3, sep=', ')
1, 2, 3
```

Normally, `print` will add a new line to the end. `end` lets you change that:

```
>>> print('Hello.', end='')
Hello.>>>
```

Normally `print` will write to standard out. `file` lets you change that:

```
>>> with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
...     print("Hello, world!", file=f)
...
```

Normally `print` does not explicitly flush the stream. If you want to avoid an extra `sys.stdout.flush()`, you can use `flush`. The effect of this is usually hard to see, but trying this without `flush=True` should make it visible:

```
>>> import time
>>> while True:
...     print('.', end='', flush=True)
...     time.sleep(0.5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Python 2 doesn't have a `sep` equivalent because `print` wasn't a function and couldn't be passed arguments. The closest you could do was with `join`:

```
 print ' '.join([value, ...])
```

As for `file`, you'd have to use this (awkward, in my opinion) syntax:

```
print >> sys.stdout, ' '.join([value, ...])
```

I'm not going to copy/paste the documentation here, so read it if you want to know what those arguments are for.